# How to find the number of tosses a biased coin goes through until a tail occurs?

Tags: probability

I am unsure of how to solve this question:

The probability of a head occurring when a biased coin is tossed is p, where p<1. Let the random variable X represent the number of tosses up to and including the first toss on which a tail occurs.

Explain why the probability of P(X = n) = p^n-1 * (1-p)

I am unsure where to start for this question. I tried using a tree diagram but it didn't work. How do I solve this?

Comment: This is a geometric distribution. For P(X = n) = p^(n-1) * (1-p), it is because the first $(n-1)$ tries are all failures (i.e. all heads), so p^(n-1), then for the last try (the $n$ trial), u want the a tail which has the probability of (1-p). So the required probability is P(X = n) = p^n-1 * (1-p)

Comment: Probability of $k$ is probability of $k-1$ heads and one tail: $p^{k-1}(1-p)$. Probability of $1$: $(1-p)$, of $2$: $p(1-p)$, of $3$: $p^2(1-p)$, ... Expected duration: $1(1-p)+2p(1-p)+3p^2(1-p)+\dots$

Comment: @ArcNeoepi Sorry is this the binomial distribution? How do you know that you need to times the p^(n-1) and (1-p)?

Comment: Sorry, I just read it's geometric distribution. For geometric distribution, I thought the exponent always goes on top of the q (like the 1-p) or is it not always?

Comment: It's actually how u define it. This qn defines p as the probability of getting a head in a toss. But the qn want u to find the probability of obtaining a tail. So X~Geo(1-p) instead of X~Geo(p) where X is the number of tosses. Success=getting a tail (ie 1-p), failure= getting a head (ie p)

Comment: @ChristopherU'Ren: unless I see otherwise, I assume that coin tosses are independant. This means that the probability of two events in a given order is the product of their individual probabilities.

Comment: Note that $$\begin{align}\sum_{k=0}^\infty kx^{k-1} &=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}x^k\\ &=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\frac1{1-x}\\ &=\frac1{(1-x)^2}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$n-1$ is the number of failures (heads) where n is the number of tosses to the first success (tail). To get $n-1$ failures would be a probability of $(p)^{(n-1)}$. Therefore the probability of a first success with $n$ tosses is $P(X=n) = (p)^{(n-1)}\cdot (1-p)$.

Comment: Sorry, is there a formula for this? How do you know to multiply the (p)(n−1) and (1−p)? For the geometric distribution formula, I thought the exponential always goes on top of the q, or am I wrong? https://magoosh.com/statistics/what-is-the-geometric-distribution-formula/

Comment: The confusing thing is that $p$ is usually stated as the probability of success whereas you've stated it as (1-p). The geometric probability formula is $P(X=n) = (1-p)^{(n-1)}\cdot p$ but because the way the question was stated we swap around $p$ and $(1-p)$. A series of $n-1$ failures in this question is $p\cdot p\cdot p$ ..........$n-1$ times which equals $p^{(n-1)}$.